# How to create a password input with Dojo?

Tags: javascript, passwords, dojo

I really get confused when I'm attempting to create a password input with Dojo, the following is the related code fragment:

HTML: `<input id="password" type="password">`

JavaScript:

```
var passwordInput = new ValidationTextBox({
    name: "password",
}, "password");
```

I seems that the input with type of password doesn't work and the below is the effect sketches， which is the plaintext:
[image]

Meanwhile, I cannot find another Dojo widget can use as a password purpose, and I also don't think Dojo doesn't support it. So can anybody give me ideas on this issue?

Thnaks in advance.

Comment: which dojo version do you use?

Comment: and which browser & version? 'cause this works for me see http://jsfiddle.net/HkXtr/1/

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the `type` param

```
var passwordInput = new ValidationTextBox({
    type: "password"
}, "password");
```

Comment: Yes it does. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/L5Pf6/), which is a modified version the one given in @mkr9's answer, and uses `ValidationTextBox` instead of `TextBox`.

Answer (score 4):

You can create it by the following two ways:

1.Declarative example:

```
<input id="password" name="password" type="password"  required="true" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" tabindex="0" invalidMessage:'Please enter password.'">
```

2.Programmatic example

```
var password = new ValidationTextBox({
    name: "password",
    type: "password"
}, "password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ValidationTextBox use TextBox and set property type:'password'

```
new TextBox({
  type:'password'
},'pass');
```

you can check it live [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JdLTa/2/)